# What's the best way to write fade in out function?

Tags: animation

I want to create a continuous fade in and out.

I'd like to have some function `F(time)` that returns values increasing from 0 to 255, then from 255 back down to -255, and repeats, as time progresses.

Comment: Rephrase your question, so we can make better answers.

Comment: Rephrased the question. : )

Comment: This isn't really related to game dev and has a certain lack of details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the question has been answered but just for old times sake here is the optimized classic way (works only with fixed steps but takes only 2 bytes ;-) )

```
//init:
unsigned char value=0;
unsigned char d=1;


//in loop:
value+=d;
if((value==0) || (value==255))
 d=-d;
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm completely missing something, but wouldn't d=-d; result in an unsigned underflow? I'd understand if d were a (*signed*) char.

Comment: Well, it would be simpler to read but no difference actually except the need for extra conversions... Adding the underflowed d (which for '-1' has a value of 255) will act as a -1 to the value 'value'.

Comment: I see, of course *value* will also wrap around and end up one less than before if you just add 255. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 10):

What you're looking for is a [periodic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) like Sine.  Here's how you can use Sine to achieve what you're looking for:

```
Create a loop counter
Begin your fade loop
    Increment your loop counter
    fade_amount = 255 * sin(loop_counter)
```

It's as simple as that.  Since `sin(loop_counter)` will cycle from -1.0 through 0 to 1.0 and back again, you just multiply it by the maximum value you want.

Comment: What about loop_counter won't it overflow?

Comment: @Beast The sine function repeats every 2π radians or 360 degrees, so you could always add something like `while(loop_counter >= twoPi) loopCounter -= twoPi` at the end to wrap it back and prevent an eventual overflow.

Comment: In addition to Davids comment: If you want your values to go through `-1` and `1` exactly, then you get best results if you use fractions of π as your `loop_counter`. Eg. `loop_counter += PI * 0.1`. The smaller the fraction, the slower the fade in-out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a tweening library to smoothly fade in and out such as cpptweener.

http://code.google.com/p/cpptweener/

Comment: -1 for very poor quality C++. I would not recommend this library; it can't even get basic arithmetic correct.